# How do I Integrate RevMob with LibGdx

Tags: android, frameworks, admob, libgdx, revmob

I found the RevMob Documentation for integration with Android.But since I am using LibGDX as my framework I am totally clueless how to do it.I did find one method for integrating AdMob. But that is a banner Ad and I want to have full screen RevMob adds. [Here](http://sdk.revmob.com/android.html) is the link to the RevMob Docs.Would anyone please tell me briefly how do I implement it in LibGDX?

Comment: This is how to do platform specific stuff: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationPlatformSpecific
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9072&p=41323#p41323 This is for banner ads(Admob but would work with any other, I used it in Airpush). Which uses the technique from the links above. http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx ;)

Comment: Ey, could you post the answer? Im having the same issue

Comment: Here is the post that I followed : http://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/libgdx-and-revmob-integration/    A word of caution: Be careful while putting the lines in the manifest file.If you copy paste, some charecters may get misinterpreted by eclipse.So it is better if you type them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already implemented it but I'm having an issue refreshing the game view. If there is a banner active on the screen and I minimize the game, after maximizing it, a lot of times the game view appears in black... :/. It just draws the banner view... do you know how to refresh the game view? :)

Comment: I am using admob for the banners and I dropped Revmob from my project and integrated appflood. I haven't had that problem.So sorry, can't really help with that.

Comment: Find the detailed tutorial on integrating revmob with libgdx here [http://digitalwolfstudio.in/integrating-revmob-with-libgdx](http://digitalwolfstudio.in/integrating-revmob-with-libgdx)

Comment: Hi prithul, would you mind to edit the accepted answer to resolve the  loop, I'd do but did not find your mentioned result of google search. If possible, could you avoid a link only answer? regard bummi

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a Interface in the main LibGDX project and implement it in your android Project like this....

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.revmob.RevMob;
import com.revmob.RevMobAdsListener;
import com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.RevMobFullscreen;

public class RevMobDisplay implements AdInterface{

        public RevMobAdsListener listener;
        private RevMobFullscreen fullscreen;


        private MainActivity activity;
        private RevMob revmob;

        public RevMobDisplay(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.activity = mainActivity;
        revmob = RevMob.start(activity);

        //UNCOMMENT THIS CODE AFTER YOU HAVE PUBLISHED YOUR GAME LIVE
        //USE WHILE TESTING YOUR GAME DURING DEVELOPMENT
        revmob.setTestingMode(RevMobTestingMode.WITH_ADS);

        listener = new RevMobAdsListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRevMobAdDisplayed() {
            Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdDisplayed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRevMobAdReceived() {
            Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdReceived");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRevMobAdNotReceived(String message) {
            Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdNotReceived");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRevMobAdDismiss() {
            Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdDismiss");
            fullscreen.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRevMobAdClicked() {
            Log.i("[RevMob]", "onAdClicked");
            revmob.openAdLink(activity, "6753b82ad690ad146c233a6d",this);
        }
    };
          // Pre-load it without showing it
           fullscreen = revmob.createFullscreen(activity, "6753b82ad690ad146c233a6d", listener); 
           revmob.setTimeoutInSeconds(5);
           }


        @Override
        public void showAds(boolean show) {
                if(show){
                        if(fullscreen == null)
                        fullscreen = revmob.createFullscreen(activity, "6753b82ad690ad146c233a6d", listener);
                        fullscreen.show();
                }
                else{
                        fullscreen.hide();
                }          
        }
}
```

Now that you have implemented everything...change the default constructor of the Main Project to something like this

```
initialize(new MyGame(new RevMobDisplay(this)), cfg);
```

Now you can easily show ads whenever you want it to show in your game by calling

```
MyGame.revmobAdInterface.showAds(true);
```

Find the detailed tutorial on integrating revmob with libgdx here

http://digitalwolfstudio.in/integrating-revmob-with-libgdx